# I don't understand why i am getting this error with ts-jest and sequelize

Tags: typescript, jestjs, sequelize.js

I'm working on an API using nodeJs, TypeScript, Sequelize and jest (ts-jest) and there is an error i'm sure to understand.

i have the follwing code :

```
router.get('/hotels', async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const hotels = await Hotel.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: Visit,
      },
      {
        model: Sector,
      },
    ],
    ...(req.query.limit && { limit: req.query.limit }),
    order: [
      ['name', 'ASC'],
      [Visit, 'date', 'ASC NULLS FIRST'],
    ],
  });
  res.send(hotels);
} catch (error) {
  res.status(404).send({ error });
}
```

});

but when i run the command 'jest' it show me this error :

```
 app/routes/hotel.ts:33:40 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ order: ([string, string] | [typeof Visit, string, string])[]; include: ({ model: typeof Visit; } | { model: typeof Sector; })[]; } | { order: ([string, string] | [typeof Visit, string, string])[]; include: ({ ...; } | { ...; })[]; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOptions | undefined'.
  Type '{ order: ([string, string] | [typeof Visit, string, string])[]; limit: string | QueryString.ParsedQs | string[] | QueryString.ParsedQs[]; include: ({ model: typeof Visit; } | { ...; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'FindOptions'.
    Types of property 'limit' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.

 33     const hotels = await Hotel.findAll({
                                           ~
 34       include: [
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
... 
 46       ],
    ~~~~~~~~
 47     });
    ~~~~~
```

it think there is a problem with types that ts-jest seem to not understand. I can provide more details if you ask me.

I'm using jest ^25.5.4, ts-jest^25.5.1 and Sequelize

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Maxime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the stack, but it looks like it knows that the type of `req.query.limit` is a string, and the methods expects the limit prop to be a number.

if you are sure that `req.query.limit` is a number you can probably replace:

`...(req.query.limit && { limit: req.query.limit }),`

with

`{limit: req.query.limit ? Number(req.query.limit) : null}`

or do more advanced parses to convert limit query param to number as you see fit